# перенос фигурных скобок

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

```
//при нажатии enter фигурная скобка не переностся нормально
if(){
} ◀◀
//хотелось бы так

if(){
  //курсор
}
```

Comment: А в чем трудность или проблема, в программе VSCode данное действие есть автоматическим. Вам нужно его отключить или что?

Comment: @pyduti у меня с самого начала установки vs code видимо не активна эта функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

короче методом тыка я понял что за это отвичает параметр`"editor.language.brackets": []` после того как я его убрал из settings.json все зароботало

Answer (score 0):

попробуй нажать Enter+tab, мне обычно помогает

Comment: к сожалению не помогло но все равно спасибо